# Estimate compressed size of data

Tags: algorithm, file, compression, zip

For example I have some folder with files which I want to compress, but I want to estimate the size of archive before creating it. If it needed algorithm can use temp file of predefined size orders smaller then folder size.

Can anyone suggest such algorithm or existing compression program?

Comment: If you want an exact result, then you have to compress the files in background and check the size of the resulting file. If you want some heuristic the result would be anywhere between `0.01 * sizeOfFolder` and `sizeOfFolder` depending on the files. Why do you need this information?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind For example I have 12 Gb file and want to copy it to 5 Gb disk, so I don't want it to start to work and then tell me that there is no enough space, but I want to check before run how much Gb of storage needed(depending on my data and compression scheme).

Comment: the only feasible way i can think of is assigning a ratio for every file type: (0.3 for .txt, .99 for .exe, 0.9 for .jpg, etc.) and then calculate the size: `for each file: sum+=size(file)*ratio(file)`. But still then it would be possible to write .txt files which won't compress better than .99 and your estimate would be totally wrong

Answer (score 8):

One way you could do it would be to read, say, the first megabyte of the file, compress it in memory, and see what the compression ratio is. Then multiply that by the total file size and you'll get an *estimate* of the total compressed size.

That technique assumes that the rest of the file is similar to the first megabyte (i.e. has a similar amount of entropy), which is typically the case for most types of files that we work with. But you could run across cases where the first megabyte compresses really well but the rest doesn't. Or vice-versa.

You could perhaps get a better idea of the overall compression ratio by selecting samples from multiple points throughout the file. So read the first megabyte and compress it. Do the same thing for samples at regular (or random, I suppose) points throughout the file. Say, for example, you read and compress five one-megabyte samples and each one gives you a compression ratio in the range of 0.6 to 0.7. It's highly likely that the overall compression ratio of the file will be in that range.